# Stripe confirm Card details for swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I using CardIO and stripe for quick payment set for an app.  I'm going through stripes documentation to find out how to validate quickly without setting up a full account.

My first question is what does textField.isValid confirm?  Is there some call to stripe to confirm the card or is a simple content check?

```
func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
    // Toggle buy button state
    buyButton.enabled = textField.isValid
}
```

Second if it does confirm that the card is valid was is the difference between this and the code below?  Is the token only to used when a purchase is about to be executed?

```
func userDidProvideCreditCardInfo(cardInfo: CardIOCreditCardInfo!, inPaymentViewController paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {
        if let info = cardInfo {
            let str = NSString(format: "Received card info.\n Number: %@\n expiry: %02lu/%lu\n cvv: %@.", info.redactedCardNumber, info.expiryMonth, info.expiryYear, info.cvv)
            print(str)

            //dismiss scanning controller
            paymentViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            //create Stripe card
            let card: STPCardParams = STPCardParams()
            card.number = info.cardNumber
            card.expMonth = info.expiryMonth
            card.expYear = info.expiryYear
            card.cvc = info.cvv

            //Send to Stripe
            getStripeToken(card)

        }
    }
```

Edit:  I should add that I'm curious if I have to begin processing a payment to confirm a card or can I do that beforehand? (example: the exp date you entered is incorrect).

Comment: The Stripe SDK is open source so you can look at the source of the method to see what it does but no it doesn't make any calls to Stripe, just local validation that it could represent a valid card.

Comment: @dan That's not true - token creation involves an API call to Stripe with your Publishable Key.

Answer (score 0):

`textField.isValid` in that case [validates that each of the `STPPaymentCardTextField` fields are valid](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/1cf5109d1e0095c255450fd30706871bc9dab012/Stripe/STPPaymentCardTextFieldViewModel.m#L101); that doesn't involve any API calls to Stripe.

The second example does make a 'create Token' API call to Stripe, though that also doesn't actually validate the Card; it's not until you use it to [create a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) or [store it on an existing Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card), or to [create a Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), that it gets validated.